# Why does this statement error say "String Cannot Be Converted to Component"?

Tags: java

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("#1", "#2", "Total", "Result");
```

Trying to show create the display of the results but Im getting the error for this statement saying "String cannot be converted to component.

Comment: did you check the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of that method is the `Component`

```
    showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int messageType)
```

You are passing in a `String` (#1), and that isn't a `Component`.